# Getting image file path from PreviewMouseDown event (WPF/C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, uri, blend

I'm making an image viewer. I have a mouse event that is supposed to trigger when an image (or child of StackPanel in this case), is clicked. The event is triggered as intended. The problem is, since the pathfile of the images is different depending on whichever is selected (in which directory, etc.), I just don't know how to get the pathfile of the specific image that is currently clicked on. The directory depends on whichever folder is loaded, so the pathfile could be different everytime.

If you scroll all the way down to *Image_Load()*, I have the Pic.Fill which is a reference to the rectangle that is being filled with the image. I'm trying to find the first parameter for *Uri(_,_)*, which is supposed to be where the @"path" of the current image is.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        List<string> paths = new List<string>();
        string[] extension = new[] { ".jpg", ".png", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".bmp", ".tif", ".tiff" };

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

            if (fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath);
                FileLocation.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
            }
        }

        private void OpenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadPhotos();
        }

        private void LoadPhotos()
        {

            try
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(fbd.SelectedPath);
                foreach (var fi in di.GetFiles().Where(f => extension.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower())).ToArray())
                {
                    paths.Add(fi.FullName);
                }

                Photos.ItemsSource = paths;

            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File not found.", e.Source);  
            }

        }

        private void Image_Load(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
                // What is the reference here?
                Pic.Fill = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(/*Insert pathfile here*/, UriKind.Absolute)) };
         }

    }
}
```

Here's my .xaml. I've analyzed it to see a reference but the only thing that stands out is the Image Source, which I've tagged with a comment. It's set to { Binding . } which I'm going to assume means, whatever image is referenced. But how do I connect that variable reference to my *Image_Load()*? (which is declared on the instantiation of ListBox)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1081" Width="1720.5">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,2,-0.578">
        <Button x:Name="OpenButton" Content="Load" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="1166.374,932.042,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145.666" Background="#FFDDDDDD" FontSize="24" Click="OpenButton_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="BrowseButton" Content="Browse" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="58.666,932.042,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="134.166" Background="#FFDDDDDD" FontSize="24" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Pic" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="878.767" Margin="58.666,34.733,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1253.374"/>    
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Width="327.46" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1339.04,34.733,0,137.078" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
            <StackPanel Width="327.46" RenderTransformOrigin="0.516,0.496" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="878.085">    
                <ListBox x:Name="Photos" 
                 Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Height="876" PreviewMouseDown="Image_Load">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Width="300" Height="100">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                /* Image Source? */
                                <Image Source="{Binding .}" Grid.Column="0"/>


                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>     
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <TextBlock x:Name="FileLocation" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="192.832,948.542,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="973.542" Foreground="#FF515151" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="14"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I've been learning on the way using Blend-- some youtube tutorials here and there. I've tried to look for a solution online but all the questions about it usually involve a static and specific directory. This is my first program and the only thing I need is that darn path file reference. There are so many object reference so I just don't even know how to wrap my head around it, being so unfamiliar with these classes. Some assistance would be very much appreciated! :)

Comment: It is difficult tell from your usage details. It appears that you are trying to execute multiple passes of the Button_Click, but when you are executing LoadPhotos, it will only operate against the *last* path selected. You are not collecting the path info after each directory, and that should be occurring. There are a number of approaches to solve this, but the easiest is to include the path info with the LoadPhotos call, and do that for every Button_Click event. NOT the OpenButton_Click event. When you resolve this, you will also locate other issues....

Comment: Do I understand it right that you want to display a list of images, have user click on one of them and then have that image displayed as background in the `Pic` rectangle?

Comment: Since you do `Photos.ItemsSource = paths`, the `SelectedItem` property of the ListBox contains the full path of the selected image.

Comment: That said, you may also get the paths list like this: `paths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(fbd.SelectedPath).Where(f => extension.Contains(Path.GetExtension(f).ToLower())).ToList();`

Comment: That's correct @Michal Krejčí

Comment: @Clemens  When I use 'paths' as the first parameter for Uri, it tells me that it could not convert from Systems.Generic.List<string> to string. I tried to do paths.ToString(), which was valid, but it returns the error that "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determiend"

Comment: Creating a single Uri from multiple paths makes no sense. Why would you want to do that at all? You already assign `Photos.ItemsSource = paths;` and have `<Image Source="{Binding .}"/>` in the ItemTemplate. That should work.

Comment: nvm. I just understood what you meant previously. It makes sense now. I just had to reanalyze what I was doing. Thanks @Clemens ! It is working. I just used the SelectedItem property as reference but I also had to put it under a 'if not-null condition'.